# Android SetInexactRepeating isn't firing at all

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, repeat, android-pendingintent

I have an android setInexactRepeating placed inside of my onCreate that never fires. I have a log inside of it to make sure that it's actually executing, and that doesn't seem to fire, as well as the events that I have planned for it. I want it to go off every 10 seconds, but it doesn't even seem to go off even the first time.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("Restart", "First");
    Intent toRun = new Intent(this, AlarmRestart.class);
    PendingIntent pendingToRun = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, toRun, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pendingToRun); 
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000L, pendingToRun);

    Log.d("Restart", "Second");
}
```

This is in the other file:

```
public class AlarmRestart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Restart", "Third");
    }
}
```

This is what "adb shell dumpsys alarm" says

```
com.packageName.restart
5715ms running, 64 wakeups
3 alarms: flg=0x14 cmp=com.packageName.restart/.AlarmRestart
61 alarms: flg=0x14 cmp=com.packageName.restart/.reciever.AlarmRestart
```

Comment: Could `alarm.cancel()` be part of the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That should only be canceling the previous setInexactRepeating, I tried it without it and still had the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem :/

```
        <reciever android:name="com.appName.restart.AlarmRestart" android:enabled="true" />
```

It's spelled receiver....not reciever. Seriously, XML needs an error checker. I'm still marking CommonWares answer as the accepted one, because he solved several other issues that I would have run into later.

Comment: Yup, my dumb co-worker did the same thing and we looked at it for an hour.

Answer (score 8):

`AlarmRestart` is a `BroadcastReceiver`. It is not a `Service`. Yet you are trying to use a `getService()` `PendingIntent`. That will not work. Change `getService()` to `getBroadcast()`, and you should have better luck.

Comment: That is something I definitely did not realize there was a difference with. Thank you. I'm modifying my code to reflect your suggestion, but it's still skipping the Broadcast Receiver without an error message.

Comment: @Lethjakman: First, you may as well switch to `setRepeating()`, as you cannot do inexact repeating of arbitrary intervals, only the ones that are listed in the docs for `setInexactRepeating()`. Second, you might want to schedule the first occurrence to be slightly in the future. Beyond that, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` from your command line to get a log of all registered `AlarmManager` alarms, and see what is there for your app.

Comment: I was looking for a command that does that! I was starting to think it didn't exist! Even more intriguing though, it says that my app has woken up 335 times...That's definitely a huge help though. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just resorting to a "setRepeating" or not, but for future reference now that it's all working, I tried a "setInexactRepeating" with this code and it's responding as it should. Thank you again for your answers, they were extremely helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't the code use 'SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()' instead of 'System.currentTimeMillis()'?

Answer (score 2):

You may use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() in an ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP alarm, instead of System.currentTimeMillis()